# mysql linked tables, return null if not present in connecting table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables that have a many-to-many relation, using a 3rd table.
Table 1 colors:

```
____________
id | color | 
____________
1 | red  |     
2 | blue |    
3 | yellow |    
4 | orange |    
5 | green |
```

table 2 content: (Table content is not really relevant for the query, I add it for completeness.)

```
id | itemname 
1 | item1     
2 | item2     
3 | item3
```

...

table 3 is the connecting table colors_content

```
id | content_id | color_id
1 | 1 | 1 
2 | 1 | 2 
3 | 1 | 5 
4 | 2 | 1 
5 | 3 | 1 
6 | 4 | 4
```

I want to return *all* colors + a way to figure out which ones are already linked to the content_id I am querying, so as an example, so for item.id=1 the result should be:

```
colors.id | colors.color | colors_content.content_id
1 | red | 1 (this can be anything, like a boolean)
2 | blue | 1
3 | yellow | null
4 | orange | null
5 | green | 1
```

again: it is a many-to-many relation, I need to output exactly 1 of each color, with a way to know if the queries item is already linked to it.

I have tried joining in different ways but I can not seem to find the correct syntax that includes the null values for unlinked colors.

```
SELECT c.* FROM `colors` c left join colors_content cc on cc.color_id=c.id where cc.content_id=1
```

only returns the 3 linked colors for item 1, not the 2 others.

edit:
This quite convoluted query seems to do the trick (although I am unclear why the group statement will not randomly choose between the queried id and the 0 value), but I must be missing a more obvious solution:

```
select * from ( SELECT c.id , c.color, cc.content_id as present FROM colors c JOIN colors_content cc ON c.id=cc.color_id WHERE cc.content_id=7 UNION select id , color, 0 as present from colors) as resulttable group by color
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the check for the `content_id` in the `ON` clause and then check if the `color_id` of `colors_content` is `NULL`.

```
SELECT c.id,
       c.color,
       cc.colorid IS NULL exists_for_content_id
       FROM colors c
            LEFT JOIN colors_content cc
                      ON cc.color_id = c.id
                         AND cc.content_id = 1;
```

(This assumes that `(colors.id)`, `(content.id)` and `(colors_content.content_id, colors_content.color_id)` are not nullable and unique.)

Comment: hi sticky bit, thans for your answer. The is null exists_for_content_id returns an error (unexpected token), however if I just leave that part out it seems to work! So thank you very much